# AWS Sagemaker fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com/my/repo.git': terminal prompts disabled

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, gitlab, amazon-sagemaker

I want to integrate my private gitlab repository into AWS Sagemaker.

I added git repository on Sagemaker using https protocol (it allows only this protocol) and saved secrets(username and password of my gitlab account) for git repo.

When I run notebook instance by linking git repo, it failed with following message.

`fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com/my/repo.git': terminal prompts disabled`

Is there any step I am missing?

Comment: @phd  Did you try this on sagemaker?

This issue is specific to sagemaker, not simple issue related to git.

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sagemaker-git-repository/) states that this error can occur in the following scenarios:

- The Git repository URL is wrong.
- The password contains a forward slash character ("/").

But in my case, what fixed the problem was adding the `.git` at the end of the address. More specifically, the following format: `https://gitlab.com/username/repository` was causing error; changing it to: `https://gitlab.com/username/repository.git` fixed the issue for me.

I have also double checked that the above two conditions were met prior to adding `.git`, so it seems like the documentation was off.